# Windows application(C#.net) APPCRASH when IE9 is installed in the computer

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control

i developed a windows application based on google analytics...my programming language is C#(c-sharp)...

i have 2 Webbrowser controls in my form,which uses the IE version installed in the PC...my app. is working with other versions,jus not with IE9...it crashes in between and sometimes at the start also....its a .net framework 4 application...and it also uses ABCPDF.NET 7.042(professional)...

Please help...

Thanx...:)

Error :

> Problem signature:
>       Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
>       Application Name: Google Ananlytics Application.exe
>       Application Version: 1.0.0.0
>       Application Timestamp: 4f9e8e3c
>       **Fault Module Name: ieframe.dll
>       Fault Module Version: 9.0.8112.16443**
>       Fault Module Timestamp: 4f4c2cfa
>       Exception Code: c0000005
>       Exception Offset: 0009ffff
>       OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
>       Locale ID: 1033
>       Additional Information 1: 0a9e
>       Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>       Additional Information 3: 0a9e
>       Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>       Read our privacy statement online:
>       http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>       If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
>       C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Comment: run your program in the debugger and find the line of code that results in the crash. Then add this line of code to your answer. I'm sure that then you'll have a better chance that someone will be able to help you than you have now.